# Refreshing JPanel and Switching JTabbedPane in ActionPerfmored

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jtextfield

```
 private void buttonAddJobActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

   try {  

       retrieveID();
       String sqlStm = "INSERT INTO Job (employerID,title,description,type,salary,benefits,vacancies,closing,requirement,placement,applyTo,status,posted,location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 


       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStm);
       pst.setInt(1,id);
       pst.setString(2,txtTitle.getText());
       pst.setString(3,areaDescription.getText());
       pst.setString(4,comboType.getSelectedItem().toString());
       pst.setString(5,txtSalary.getText());
       pst.setString(6,areaBenefits.getText());
       pst.setString(7,txtVac.getText());
       Date close; 
       close = txtDate.getDate();
       pst.setString(8,sdf.format(close));
       pst.setString(9,areaReq.getText());
       pst.setString(10,comboPlace.getSelectedItem().toString());
       pst.setString(11,txtWeb.getText());
       pst.setString(12,comboStatus.getSelectedItem().toString());
       Date now = new Date();   
       pst.setString(13,sdf.format(now));
       pst.setString(14,txtLoc.getText());
       pst.executeUpdate();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have successfully added a job");
       //empty all JTextfields
       //switch to another
```

I am trying to empty the set of `JTextFields` in the JPanel, but instead of emptying them one by one, can I just refresh the panel? if so, how do you do this. i tried `repaint()`, `revalidate()` these dont work. perhaps I am wrong here. 
I would also like to switch the `JTabbedPane` to another Pane, but this doesnt work when I try with this...

```
JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) evt.getSource();
       sourceTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

can someone show an example code how to do this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through all components that are contained in the panel, and if they are text components, clear their value. The code would be something like this:

```
private void clearTextFields(Container container)
{
    int count = container.getComponentCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Component component = container.getComponent(i);
        if (component instanceof Container) {
            clearTextFields((Container) component);
        }
        else if (component instanceof JTextComponent) {
            ((JTextComponent) component).setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

This method works recursively and takes care of the case when your panel contains another panel which contains the text fields.

Comment: Very good answer if all text-fields are placed directly into the parent Component Otherwise, you would have to recurse into swing containers.

Comment: I like this, how can we be more dyanmic to include not just JTextComponent, since parent component consist of `JTextArea`, `JComboBox` aswell as an addition `JDateChoose`

Comment: @MuminAli you should add more `else if` cases to reflect what reset means for those cases too

Comment: @mavroprovato can you adjust your answer to reflect panel addJobPanel rather than use the word component, so your passing the addJobPanel reference

Comment: @mavroprovato what do I pass in as argument? my panel?

Comment: @mavroprovato what should be passed as argument? i did this clearTextfields(addJobPanel) << which is of type JPanel, nothing happens

Comment: The argument should be the JPanel that contains your text fields

Comment: @mavroprovato  JTextArea contains `scrollpane`, how would i adjust the else if statement for JTextArea to take into account parent scrollpane

Comment: I think you should add another `else if` for `JScollPane` and get the contained component with `((JScrollPane) component).getViewport().getView()`

Comment: @mavroprovato and assign this to what? still struggling to get to JTextArea

Comment: `JTextArea a = (JTextArea)(((JScrollPane) component).getViewport().getView());
           a.setText("");` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need

Answer (score 1):

Keep all your JTextFields in a container, and iterate over that container to empty them.
So, somewhere:

```
ArrayList<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
```

After all fields are actually created (with `JTextField txtTitle = new JTextField()` or similar):

```
textFields.add(txtTitle);
textFields.add(areaDescription); 
// ... add all others here
```

And finally, when you need to clear them all:

```
for (JTextField tf : textFields) {
    tf.setText("");
}
```